# python matplotlib.patches: draw a Circle patch but keep only part of the circle

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a picture, and I have a rectangle plotted, then I wanted to plot a arc-shape element, but this element has to be precise, and it is only part of a circle that is outside the rectangle shape. So, I've tried to use Arc patch to create the same thing, but the shape doesn't match.

As a result, I am wondering if it is possible to plot the circle, but only keeps the part of it that is outside the rectangle? To be more specific, I want to discard/hide/get rid of the BLUE ARROW part in the image below, and keep the RED ARROW part, which is outside the rectangle like an Arc-shape. Is there any method to do so?
[image]

Here are my codes:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Rectangle, Arc, Ellipse

def plot_pic(ax=None, color='black', lw=2, scale = 15):
    # get the current ax if ax is None
    if ax is None:
       ax = plt.gca()


    # Plot the rectangle
    rec =  Rectangle((-(7.32 * scale / 2+ 5.5 * scale +11 * scale),0), width = (5.5 * scale * 2 + 11 * scale * 2 + 7.32 * scale), height = 16.5 * scale, linewidth = lw, color = color, fill = False)

    testCircle = Circle((0, 11 * scale), radius = 9.15 * scale, color = color, lw = lw, fill = False)


    # List of elements to be plotted
    pic_elements = [rec, testCircle]


    # Add the elements onto the axes
    for element in pic_elements:
        ax.add_patch(element)

    return ax
```

After this, run the following:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 22))
plt.xlim(-600,600)
plt.ylim(-100,1700)
plot_pic()
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really just to do what you say, you could set the facecolor of the rectangle to `white`, and the `zorder` of the circle to `0` so it gets plotted behind:

```
def plot_pic(ax=None, color='black', lw=2, scale = 15):
    # get the current ax if ax is None
    if ax is None:
       ax = plt.gca()


    # Plot the rectangle
    rec =  Rectangle((-(7.32 * scale / 2+ 5.5 * scale +11 * scale),0), width = (5.5 * scale * 2 + 11 * scale * 2 + 7.32 * scale), height = 16.5 * scale, linewidth = lw, color = color, fc='white')

    testCircle = Circle((0, 11 * scale), radius = 9.15 * scale, color = color, lw = lw, fill = False, zorder=0)


    # List of elements to be plotted
    pic_elements = [rec, testCircle]


    # Add the elements onto the axes
    for element in pic_elements:
        ax.add_patch(element)

    return ax
```

[image]

Comment: Hi sacul, I still have a question. So what is the difference of facecolor and fill here? If I still want to plot a heatmap on this figure, does the facecolor interfere with the heatmap? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `fill` is a boolean, but is unnecessary if you call `facecolor`, because I think that when you use `facecolor`, it implies `fil=True`. Using only `fill=True`, the `facecolor` defaults to black. I don't *think* that the facecolor should interfere with the heatmap, but I'm not exactly sure how you'll be plotting that...

Comment: Hi sacul, I tried to plot scatterplot on this graph with your method of plotting, the facecolor = "white" actually covers all the data points. Whether I plot the scatterplot first then plot the background or not, it still covers the scatter points. Is there anyway to use Arc to mimic the Circle's part above the box?

Comment: Oh, I got it solved....I set the zorder = 10 for the scatter plot, and all the points showed up! thanks a lot!