# Python, Matplotlib; drawing a partial circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can draw a full circle like so:

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

# Make the circle patch and add to the figure
circle = plt.Circle((1, 0), 1, color='r', fill=None)
ax.add_patch(circle)
    
# Make it a perfect circle by making it a perfect square box
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    
# Set axis so it's visible 
plt.xlim([-0.5,2.5])    
plt.ylim([-1.5, 1.5])
```

[image]

So far so good. But, what I only want a portion of the circle? For example, something that looks like this.

[image]

I could just [plot something on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573606/python-matplotlib-patches-draw-a-circle-patch-but-keep-only-part-of-the-circle) of it with the same color as the background, but that seems a little hacky. Is there a better way?

Comment: A partial circle is an arc. You just need to draw an arc instead of a circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an [`Arc`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Arc.html)?

```
from matplotlib.patches import Arc
radius = 1
arc = Arc((1, 0), radius*2, radius*2, color='b', theta1=90, theta2=360)
ax.add_patch(arc)
```

output:

[image]

output on top of the original circle:

[image]

Comment: Ahh, that's perfect! This is actually what I want. I must have missed it in the docs.